# Vim on Ubuntu Server from OSX Terminal: automatic copy does not work

Tags: macos, vim, clipboard

## The Story

I'm using vim on a Ubuntu server to develop a webpage. Most of the time I work from a Windows machine using putty. Whenever I have to copy something from vim to the Windows clipboard I just select it while holding shift (shift is necessary when using set mouse=a in .vimrc).

## The Problem

Sometimes I have to use an OSX machine. Well, no problem: Using the OSX terminal I ssh to my Ubuntu server and vim as I do using putty. The problem is: As soon as I set mouse=a it is no longer possible to easily copy content to the OSX clipboard. As long as mousa=a is not set, I can just copy content by selecting it.

## The Request

Does anyone know how to easily copy something from vim to the OSX clipboard if the "set mouse=a" line is in .vimrc?

Thank you.

/edit:

## The Solution

in .vimrc

```
set mouse=a
set term=xterm
```

Then it is possible to copy from vim in iTerm if I press "Alt" while selecting the content I want to copy.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608161/copy-text-out-of-vim-with-set-mouse-a-enabled/4608387#4608387

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but that does not work in my case. I've also tried that before.

Answer (score 0):

Select the text you want, then hit `Ctrl-insert` to copy and `Shift-insert` to paste.

Comment: No modern Macintosh keyboard includes an Insert key...

Answer (score 0):

Do you copy using mouse selection then <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>?

Doing that in plain vanilla Terminal.app works as intended here with more or less the same setup (running Vim with `set mouse=a` on a Ubuntu server via SSH in Terminal.app on MacOS X 10.6.7).

But I have installed [MouseTerm](https://bitheap.org/mouseterm/) some months ago and the *copy using mouse selection then <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>* business doesn't work when it's activated. As soon as I uncheck the "Left Click" box, copying the selected text with <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> works.

Do you have Mouseterm installed?